# How to handle file upload in selenium in windows 7

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit, automated-tests

I am writing a script in selenium using webdriver and nunit to automate my web application. I have to upload file in my application. But unable to do it.

The dialog opens while browse button is clicked, and upon selecting file the file is uploaded.

Browse

How can i do it in selenium?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Upload files using Selenium webdriver in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-files-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
Answer is already available on stack, still I am repeating:
```

find the upload button, create webelement of this and follow this code:

```
   //open upload window
    upload.click();

    //put path to your image in a clipboard
    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(<give file location>);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);

    //imitate mouse events like ENTER, CTRL+C, CTRL+V
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: I am using C# with selenium. And i have tried this driver.FindElement(By.Id("pickfiles")).SendKeys("D:\\file1.rar");

But it is not working.
I also tried using AutoIT but unable to run exe file provided by AutoIT

Comment: The element in my file is
 <button id="pickfiles" class="btn btn-browse-red browse-btn "><i class='fa fa-folder-o fa-lg'></i>Browse</button>
and it is using plupload javascript API to upload file

Comment: I resolved this issue refering this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531728/tdd-for-plupload-with-django-splinter

Comment: I have one more issue. In this case, a file uploader is using ActiveX control for uploading file(s). The issue is, I am not able to find the element to click.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void uploadFile(String locatorId, String filePath) {

WebElement fileInput = findElementExplicitWaitWithNoVisbility(By.id(locatorId), true);

fileInput.clear();
fileInput.sendKeys(filePath);}
```