# Upload a file to a read-only input field using selenium

Tags: selenium, extjs, automated-tests

I have implemented a method for uploading a file to a read-only input field. But when press the OK button, the attachment is Null. Interface Developed by using EXTjs.

```
public void uploadMyFile(String locatorId, String filePath) {

    WebElement fileInput = findElementExplicitWaitWithNoVisbility(By.id(locatorId), true);

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driverProvider.get()).executeScript(
            "arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",fileInput);

    fileInput.clear();
    fileInput.sendKeys(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Apparentrly you press  ok, quicker than the file is uploaded. Try to wait a little bit, and then press ok.

Comment: Thank you @DmitryMalinovsky. But I found a another issue. I removed read only attribute using firebug. Then copy and paste the path into input field. (Path is definitely correct) When I clicked the ok button attachment was null.

Comment: try answer available at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760330/how-to-handle-file-upload-in-selenium-in-windows-7/32775165#32775165